# What's the difference between the Like button with or without Open Graph META tags?

Tags: facebook-like, sharing, facebook-opengraph

I have a very basic website with the potential for having hundreds of pages, and would like to have a the Facebook Like button on each one.

However, before I do it, I would like to know the difference between inserting the Like button with, or WITHOUT using Open Graph META tags.

I don't want each page that visitors 'Like' to become their own Facebook pages, but I WOULD like their 'Like' to show up on their wall so their friends can see it.

Is the only real reason for using Open Graph to specify what exactly it is that you want to show up in the message and 'Like' post?? (example: 'Dave likes The Rock - IMDB' with a picture of the movie and a description underneath.)

Answer (score 1):

@Vali What you are suggesting:-

```
Including Open Graph tags on your Web page, makes your page equivalent to a Facebook Page. This means when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a connection is made between your page and the user. Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, and you have the ability to publish updates to the user.
```

is not possible. Kindly see my similar question:

[Convert my Site to Facebook Graph Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064164/convert-my-site-to-facebook-graph-object)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can add a Like button without OpenGraph. That's the easy way and with that you don't have any future connection with the person who liked your link/page.

Including Open Graph tags on your Web page, makes your page equivalent to a Facebook Page. This means when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a connection is made between your page and the user. Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, and you have the ability to publish updates to the user.

Using Open Graph you have a greater control on what you want to appear on that person's wall.

Open Graph is still beta. If you want to use OpenGraph you need to create a FB app, get the APP ID and add it to your webpage. If you want to use the simple Like button, you just add the fb:like tag and that's all.

> don't want each page that visitors 'Like' to become their own Facebook pages

This will not happen. You're the single admin of your page.

> Is the only real reason for using Open Graph to specify what exactly it is that you want to show up in the message and 'Like' post??

Yes, you can do this with Open Graph. I suggest using Open Graph if you want to post enhanced wall posts and if you want to get connected with the users who likes your page.