# Convert my Site to Facebook Graph Object

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I included Open Graph Tags to convert my web page to a Facebook page so that if I like my web page, it should appear in Likes & Interests in my Facebook profile. But its not working.

Following are the open graph tags i am including:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Proto"></meta>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=SITE_URL?>"></meta>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Proto"></meta>
<meta property="og:description" content="Lets you create prototypes for web apps." /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=SITE_URL?>images/proto.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website"></meta>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="284826761590524"/>
```

I included the Facebook Like button on my site. When I click Like, it does say Haris likes this, but this site does not appear in my Likes & Interests section. Why ???

Comment: The likes & interests section is for facebook pages that the user likes, not web pages in which the user clicked the "like" button.

Comment: But if you read the first paragraph on the following link:

[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)

It clearly says:
`Including Open Graph tags on your Web page, makes your page equivalent to a Facebook Page. This means when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a connection is made between your page and the user. Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile`

Comment: Umm, that document is old and it says before your quote that there's a new version of the open graph, in which you won't find that text. Also, I checked my "Likes" and there's not a single one there that isn't a fb page.

Comment: Well, the new documentation has nothing related to Like button. So... I guess the current Like button and the associated documentation is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

After converting to Timeline view I did find the Like i made in the Likes section.