# Differene between "like action through open graph" and "directly using fb like button"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is there any difference between the end result of these two actions:

- publishing like action through open graph
- directly using fb like button

If I publish like action through open graph then would the fb like button automatically recognizes that object as liked?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582223/whats-the-difference-between-the-like-button-with-or-without-open-graph-meta-ta

Answer (score 0):

Using open graph for Like will help to maintain a connection of your page/website to user. You can publish your updates to user's timeline using this connection.

Using only Like button will not establish such connection and you won't be able to publish any updates on user timeline and your page will not be listed as user's interests.

Reco.: use open graph

Comment: I meant using open graph api to publish like action and not using the usual fb like button along with open graph meta tags. I right now have a fb like button and also my own custom like button. If I use my custom like button to push like action to fb using open graph api, then does the fb like button solve any new purpose for me?